# Displaying li when clicking on item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am beginner in javascript. I have this list:

```
<p class="lead">parent item1</p>
<ul class="list bot-2">
    <li><a href="#">child item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">child item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">child item 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<p class="lead">parent item2</p>
<ul class="list bot-2">
    <li><a href="#">child item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">child item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">child item 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<p class="lead">parent item3</p>
<ul class="list">
    <li><a href="#">child item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">child item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">child item 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to display the matching div when one child item clicked, and hide other divs, the matching items is in this html structure:

```
<ul class="list-services">
    <li class="clearfix"></li>
    <li class="clearfix"></li>
    <li class="clearfix"></li>
</ul>
```

How I can do this, I see similar posts in stackoverflow, but it didn't have the similar structure.

Comment: How do you define "matching div"?

Comment: the first link matchs the first .clearfix

Comment: your html doesnt contain any "div" element

Comment: sorry, I mean li, I'll update the header title

Comment: So if I click a link the first link in any of these .list uls it will show me up the first in .list-services?

Comment: yes, please feel free to update the html structure if you find other better structure

Comment: Anything against jQuery? It would make it somehow easier.

Comment: @wumm no problem, use it

Comment: Question asking tips: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could use this:

```
$(".list a").click(function(){
   var x = $(this).parents(".list").children().get();
   var find = $(this).parent().get(0);
   var nth = x.indexOf(find) + 1;
   $(".list-services .clearfix:not(:nth-child(" + nth + "))").hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wumm/v7Ks7/1/

`var x = $(this).parents(".list").children().get();` gets the current `.list` children.

Then `var find = $(this).parent().get(0);` find is set to the `li`in which this a was.

And now `nth` is set to the index of this `li` in the current `.list`. (1 is added because CSS has a 1 based index)

Last thing: hiding anything else then the `nth` link in `.list-services`

Comment: How could you understand what the OP asks for ?'I need to display the matching div'-no `div` is in the OP .

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with plain javascript as well, here's the jQuery solution:

```
$('a').on('click', function (event) {
    $('.clearfix').hide();
    $('.clearfix').eq($(this).closest('li').prevAll('li').length).show();
});
```

The `$(this).closest('li').prevAll('li').length` bit gives the index of the clicked child item by finding the immediate `li` parent and counting the number of previous `li` tags inside the parent `ul` tag. Then we just show the `.clearfix` item with that index using `eq` and `show`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/4VwCA/1/)